# Publishing packages in nested scopes

Tags: angular, npm, angular5

I want to use `@organization-scope/package/sub-package` in npm.

My package.json is as follows:-

```json
{
  "name": "@once/ui",
  ...
  ...
}
```

If I do it like this:-

```json
{
  "name": "@once/ui/select-box",
  ...
  ...
}
```

It gives me an error saying *invalid name*.

I am using angular 5. Can someone help me do achieve the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as a nested scope in NPM.

Trying to import `@once/ui/select-box` would give you a file called `select-box.js` from within the root of the `@once/ui` package - you can utilize this behaviour to get something close to what you're trying to achieve, but publishing a package with multiple slashes in the name is not possible.