# Is it possible to use different declaration files for different versions of TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, npm, peer-dependencies

I have some type definitions that I want to turn into an npm package because I use them in multiple, unrelated projects.  (I would likely call it `@dfoverdx/ts-magic`.)  Some of these projects are using 3.x, and some are using >=4.2, where [leading and middle rest elements in tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#leadingmiddle-rest-elements-in-tuple-types) were introduced.

Is it possible to write multiple declaration files that only use the types that work in the user's version of TypeScript?

There are four ways I can think of that *might* work but which I do not know enough about to implement, if they're even possible.

1. Using the [`lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) value in `tsconfig.json`, the user could specify which ts-magic declaration file to include.  Then each declaration file could use a triple-slash directive to reference the previous version's declaration file.
2. I could have multiple sub-packages with dependencies on the previous sub-packages.  I would much rather not go this route, especially since [there is no such thing as a nested scope in NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49881874/3120446), and I would not want to use a different scope than my GitHub username, nor would I want to maintain multiple separate packages under the `@dfoverdx` scope.

   Therefore we run into another issue:  some of these types strongly type global object methods
   such as
   [Object.fromEntries()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559490/strongly-type-a-map-of-object-keys-values-to-an-object-with-the-same-keys-but-di?r=SearchResults),
   and things declared within `declare global {}` ambient contexts--as
   far as I know--can't be limited to the files that include the
   declaration file it was declared in.  That is, if my project's index.ts imported `@dfoverdx/ts-magic/3.8`, because I'm importing `@dfoverdx/ts-magic` at all, it would include every declaration file of the package.
3. Some magic in `package.json` using `peerDependencies` or some other property I'm unaware of.
4. Some sort of [triple-slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html).  I suspect [this is not the way](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EoNxTMhVoAINuE9.jpg).

I can't imagine this isn't a way to do this somehow.  Thoughts on the right way?

Comment: Another work around: increment the major version and let npm sort of the right version to include. `~1.0.0` is typescript 3 compatible, and `>2.0.0` is typescript 4.2 compatible. You could still push updates to both major versions.

Comment: @AlexWayne That may be exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [typesVersions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#version-selection-with-typesversions) property in `package.json` file.